# Submit form to another application

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

So I started to play around with cakePHP after i did the blog tutorial (yes im new), and i would like to do something complicated. Like, theres a comment form, which is simple it contains Name and the Comment. And I would like to send the data to another application in the same host, which is save this comment in the DB. Currently the Comments/add.ctp saves it.

Thanks for any advice!

So theres the CommentsControll.php

```
<?php

  class CommentsController extends AppController{
    public $components = 'Session'
    public function add(){
      if($this->request->is('POST')){
        $this->Comment->create();
        if($this->Comment->save($this->request->data)){
            $this->Session->setFlash('Your comment is saved!')
        }
    }
  }
}
?>
```

And theres the Comments/add.ctp file

```
<?php

echo $this->Form->create('Comment');
echo $this->Form->input('name', array(
    'label' => 'Your Name'
));
echo $this->Form->input('commenttext',array(
    'label' => 'Your Comment'
));
echo $this->Form->end('Submit');
?>
```

Comment: What specifically does this **send the data to another application in the same host** mean? Save in a different database? Send via REST web service?

Comment: Hi!
I mean the data from this form is sent to another application like (Saver) which is validate the data if the data is validated it saves into the DB. and send a response to the Comment application which is Flash the ('Your comment is saved') text to the user.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution** [HttpSocket](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/httpsocket.html#httpsocket)

CakePHP includes an `HttpSocket` class which can be used easily for making requests. It is a great way to communicate with external webservices, or remote apis.

```
// in your controller

App::uses('HttpSocket', 'Network/Http'); // This should be at the top of your Controller


  class CommentsController extends AppController{
    public $components = 'Session'
    public function add(){
      if($this->request->is('POST')){
        $this->Comment->create();
        $HttpSocket = new HttpSocket();
        $response = $HttpSocket->post('http://example.com/add', $this->request->data));
        // Get the status code for the response.
        $code = $results->code;
        if($code == 200) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Your comment is saved!');
        } else { 
            $this->Session->setFlash('Opps! Somthing is wrong!');
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Also see here [CakePHP HttpSocket](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/httpsocket.html#httpsocket)